# Error 500 with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-500

I have tried all that it is in the old posts of stackoverflow..

I have put debug `true` (Any error is displayed, it keeps saying error 500)

It has permissions `775` in all the folders in all the files

In local works very good but online does not

I have a VPS

I have not touched the htaccess files (It is that maybe?)

I have installed a fresh laravel project and it does not work either 
watch it: [http://mechamou.com.br/public/](http://mechamou.com.br/blog/public/)

What could it be? what am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked in the web server's error logs?

Comment: Also check the laravel error logs

Comment: You probably need to setup apache virtualhost, see http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

Comment: The path of the laravel log is: `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided redirects to http://mechamou.com.br/blog/public/
I manually remove the /blog section of the url (so it becomes http://mechamou.com.br/public) and it works perfectly. So, you need to config your apache so it has the correct path to the public folder in your app.